# Android Listview question:can not use <ListView> </ListView> in layout xml?

Tags: android, xml, listview, layout

I try to write a xml like below xml,but always get an exception say
that"Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:
addView(View,LayoutParams) is not supported in Adapterview".
It is say that in layout xml can not use `<ListView> </ListView>`,and
it should be `<ListView />`and be manipulated using java code,is it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/
android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp">

    <ListView android:id="@+id/listview"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:background="#00FF00"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:drawSelectorOnTop="false">

    <TextView
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:background="#000000"
              android:text="No data"/>
  </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot put a `TextView` inside of a `ListView` this way. You need to associate a `ListAdapter` object with the `ListView`.

Comment: can you expand on your answer?? I'm having the same issue and am having a very hard time nailing it down.

Comment: @BennettVonBennett: Here is a free excerpt from one of my books that goes into more detail: http://commonsware.com/excerpt.pdf

Answer (score 0):

At last,I found scrollview is which I need.Thank you for you reply.
Like as:

```
  <ScrollView>
   <LinearLayout>
   <TextView/>
   <TextView/>
   ...or something else
   <TextView/>
   </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
```